# Can anyone help me get Jekyll installed?

Tags: jekyll

Apparently I can this error if I use 'sudo gem install jekyll' or 'gem install jekyll'

ERROR:  While executing gem ... (Errno::EACCES)
    Permission denied - /Users/antonioortiz/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p448/gems/ffi-1.9.3/ffi.gemspec

Appreciate the help!

Comment: Check permissions of the directory. Make sure root is allowed in and such. Make sure you don't have 'gem' running anywhere else so as to lock the directory.

Comment: Checked the permissions and they're set to 'read & write'...I have 'rvm' is that how you'd manage conflicting 'gems?'

Comment: What does `echo "${GEM_HOME}"` output, additionally are you able to find the path specified by the `GEM_HOME` variable within your `PATH`?... eg `grep -q -- "${GEM_HOME} <<<"${PATH}"; echo "${?}"` _should_ output `0` when everything's set-up correctly... generally with _`gem install someThing`_ one does __not__ need to resort to `sudo`, and really it can mess things up if one hasn't accounted for various edge-cases; personally I've found it to be _easier_ to have a different user account for Git/Jekyll stuff that's somewhat _locked down_ to only providing related services.

Answer (score 0):

Check folder permission, chmod to 755.

Comment: How would you do that?

Comment: Check the folder permission first, before making any changes. But in the console type 'sudo chmod -R 755 [folder]'

Comment: Thanks but didn't work...
Funny when I try'sudo gem install jekyll' I get:

ERROR:  While executing gem ... (Errno::EACCES)
    Permission denied - /Users/antonioortiz/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p448/gems/ffi-1.9.3/ffi.gemspec
antonios-Mac-Pro:newaortiz.dev antonioortiz$ sudo gem install jekyll
Successfully installed jekyll-1.4.3
1 gem installed
antonios-Mac-Pro:newaortiz.dev antonioortiz$